# How to save the output of linux command to a file in local

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, file-server, selenium

I have SSH to a server and have a syslog at `usr/local`. I am using the command

```
tail -f syslog.log | grep fps
```

and want to save the output of it to a file.

I have tried to SCP as below

```
% scp root@10.211.128.73:/usr/local/syslog.log ~/Desktop/a-file.txt
```

but got as

```
-sh: /root: Is a directory
```

Can anyone please help me out?
additionally my ultimate aim if to read the FPS values from the file through selenium. Or is it possible to read the FPS values  directly after the grep command. any suggestion would be great. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `ssh remoteserver tail -f /path/to/syslog.log | grep fps > localfile`? I don't know selenium and can't comment on the last paragraph.

Comment: what is result of `which scp` or `whereis scp` ?

Comment: I tried "tail -f syslog.log | grep fps > output.txt" after that when I tried to execute cat output.txt  then it was blank. Additionally I am doing all the above in tera term and not in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the messages on the Desktop side in real time? Because that's what the `tail -f` does. It follows the file.

`ssh -t root@10.211.128.73 "tail -f /usr/local/syslog.log | grep -i fps" >> ~/Desktop/a-file.txt`

`>` will overwrite the content of your file every time you run that command

`>>` will append the content of the `tail -f /usr/local/syslog.log | grep -i fps` to your file instead of overwrite it

If the `a-file.txt` is blank then no lines containing `fps` were found. Also, the `grep -i` option greps upper and lowercase strings. See if this can help you.